# Want to install Ubuntu 15.04 after removing windows 8 and data loss

Tags: system-installation

I am Using Windows 8 and I want to install Ubuntu 15.04 and remove Windows from my system. How do I Install Ubuntu securing my data? I mean, I do not want my data to be lost.

Comment: And why exactly you want to install a no longer supported ubuntu release?

Comment: so will you suggest me about installing 14.04

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: I suggest to you to install the latest version of `Ubuntu: 16.04` You can find it here: http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop

Answer (score 0):

What data do you want to save? If it's just your personal files, plug an external drive to your computer and copy your `c:/users/your username/libraries` (libraries stands for my documents, my downloads, my pictures, and so on), then install Ubuntu
OR
you can create a new partition on your disk, move your data on it, then install Ubuntu on your Windows partition